# I need the "if" statement to keep evaluating (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement, setinterval

I've gotta be doing something simple wrong. I'm tracking the speed of the cursor movement. The cursor has been replaced with a 50px x 50px square. If the speed is greater than or equal to 1.00, the cursor square should be red. If it's slower, it should be blue. The problem is, when I load the page the cursor is blue and does not turn red no matter how fast I move it.

To calculate the speed, I'm using [this code](http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/49/capturing-cursor-speed/)

And calling it with this code:

```
$(function() {

    var $speedometer = $('#speed');

    $('#track').cursometer({
        onUpdateSpeed: function(speed) {
            $speedometer.text(speed);
        },
        updateSpeedRate: 20
    });

        setInterval(function () {
            if (speed >= 1.00) {
                $('#cursor').css('background', 'red');
            } else {
                $('#cursor').css('background', 'blue');
            }
        }, 20);
});
```

Comment: Please show more code on how you are determining speed variable

Comment: where is `speed` defined ?

Comment: I updated the question. The speed is being calculated perfectly fine. That's not the problem, which is why I didn't post it originally.

Comment: @Chris_topher Don't assume relevant items in the question are *perfectly fine*, it's clearly not. Not stating it originally would make your question closed as *"Not Working"* without us being able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`speed` is not a global variable and not in scope of your interval. It is in the *scope* of that callback, you can not access it outside. Your console should have tons of error messages telling you that it is not defined.

```
$(function() {

    var $speedometer = $('#speed'),
         _speed = 0; 

    $('#track').cursometer({
        onUpdateSpeed: function(speed) {
            _speed = speed;
            $speedometer.text(speed);
        },
        updateSpeedRate: 20
    });

        setInterval(function () {
            if (_speed >= 1.00) {
                $('#cursor').css('background', 'red');
            } else {
                $('#cursor').css('background', 'blue');
            }
        }, 20);
});
```

BUT Why use the interval? Just put the if/else statement inside of the `onUpdateSpeed` callback.

```
$('#track').cursometer({
    onUpdateSpeed: function(speed) {
        $speedometer.text(speed);
        $('#cursor').css('background-color', speed >= 1 ? 'red' : 'blue');
    },
    updateSpeedRate: 20
});
```

Comment: My console log isn't giving me any errors. And when I enter "speed" in the console, it gives me the current speed like I'd expect. But I think I assumed wrong in this being purely a JS problem. I think I need to look at how it's relaying the info in HTML and work back from there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: From what you gave, `speed` should not be available from the console...Unless that library is poorly written and sets globals. Did you actually try what I recommended?

Comment: Ohhhh wait wait wait, I put something in the wrong order. Yes, your code does work. Thank you muchly.